# How to start another android application from code

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Launch an application from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

I want to start Another of my Android Application ( .apk ) using Android code. is it possible ? 
I have one background kind of Android Application ( Service ). It is separate Android Application. I want to start this Application from my Another Android Application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

for more :[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)